# Difference between SQL injection and nosql injection

Tags: sql, security, web-applications, nosql

Exact difference between SQL and no SQL injection.

Comment: This is better suited to a google query than a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSQL injection attack can take place on the application layer.

Application layer is the difference.